# Migrated web server to newer OS and Python version cant get Pylons web app to run

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv, python-2.6, pylons

We migrated our hosted web server from an older centos 5.5, apache 2.2, python 2.5 or 2.6 to latest version centos, apache 2.4, python 2.7. Our main web app was written in pylons with python 2.6. And was located under /home/. The hosting company didnt move the directory over so we tar'd and moved them over. Decomprssed the tar and ran the .sh to start paster and the web app. Get these errors now and am not sure where to start.

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/webapp/pylons-env/bin/paster", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

Some research suggests reinstall python but the server already has 2.7.x on it and an installed version the app was written in came over in subdirectory in the tar.

The shell script is the following and also update the full text of the error that comes out:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/webapp/pylons-env/bin/activate
cd /home/webapp/app
kill `cat paster.pid`
paster serve --daemon --log-file=prod-mt.log --pid-file=paster.pid prod-mt.ini

#sender="company@www.domain.com"
#receiver="dev@gmail.com"
#body="Thanks"
#echo $body | mail $receiver -s "App Restarted"
```

I have made some progress thanks to Audrius' post. Some things to note: there was not a requirements.txt so I did the install Pylons and install on the setup.py. I have to specify /home/webapp/pylons-env/bin/paster when I attempt to start the app, because there is now a paster in the system /bin/ which it uses if I just do a paster serve. I did delete the pylons-env in /home/webapp/ and reinstall. If I run the .sh script above I just get an "Entering Daemon Mode" message, but the paster process never starts (I have updated it to specify the paster in /home/webapp). I thought I would just try to do the standard in the documentation:

```
/home/webapp/pylons-env/bin/paster serve /home/webapp/app/prod-mt.ini
```

And I get this:

```
[root@58ck-6gpy me]# /home/webapp/pylons-env/bin/paster serve /home/webapp/app/prod-mt.ini
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/webapp/pylons-env/bin/paster", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('PasteScript==2.0.2', 'console_scripts', 'paster')()
  File "/home/webapp/pylons-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 102, in run
invoke(command, command_name, options, args[1:])
  File "/home/webapp/pylons-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 141, in invoke
exit_code = runner.run(args)
  File "/home/webapp/pylons-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 236, in run
result = self.command()
  File "/home/webapp/pylons-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/serve.py", line 284, in command
relative_to=base, global_conf=vars)
  File "/home/webapp/pylons-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/serve.py", line 329, in loadapp
**kw)
  File "/home/webapp/pylons-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 247, in loadapp
return loadobj(APP, uri, name=name, **kw)
  File "/home/webapp/pylons-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 271, in loadobj
global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/home/webapp/pylons-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 296, in loadcontext
global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/home/webapp/pylons-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 320, in _loadconfig
return loader.get_context(object_type, name, global_conf)
  File "/home/webapp/pylons-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 454, in get_context
section)
  File "/home/webapp/pylons-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 476, in _context_from_use
object_type, name=use, global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/home/webapp/pylons-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 406, in get_context
global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/home/webapp/pylons-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 296, in loadcontext
global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/home/webapp/pylons-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 320, in _loadconfig
return loader.get_context(object_type, name, global_conf)
  File "/home/webapp/pylons-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 454, in get_context
section)
  File "/home/webapp/pylons-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 476, in _context_from_use
object_type, name=use, global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/home/webapp/pylons-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 406, in get_context
global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/home/webapp/pylons-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 296, in loadcontext
global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/home/webapp/pylons-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 328, in _loadegg
return loader.get_context(object_type, name, global_conf)
  File "/home/webapp/pylons-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 620, in get_context
object_type, name=name)
  File "/home/webapp/pylons-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 646, in find_egg_entry_point
possible.append((entry.load(), protocol, entry.name))
  File "/home/webapp/pylons-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2260, in load
entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/home/webapp/app/client/config/middleware.py", line 8, in <module>
from pylons.error import error_template
ImportError: cannot import name error_template
```

Haven't changed anything, but I am getting this. Same code as above with the last few File lines replaced with:

```
  File "/home/webapp/pylons-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 640, in find_egg_entry_point
pkg_resources.require(self.spec)
  File "/home/webapp/pylons-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 728, in require
needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/home/webapp/pylons-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 626, in resolve
raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: appClient
```

Making progress, but the `paster` process will not start on the new server. This is the output when running the .sh above:

```
cat: paster.pid: No such file or directory
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
Entering daemon mode
```

Then I do `top` and don't see the process running.

Comment: Can you post the contents of the shell script which starts your webapp? And am I correctly understanding that in the new server you have both system-wide installation of Python which came with OS _and_ your old Python installation which you kept in /home?

Comment: Yes, correct, there is the system wide Python that came with the server and the installation came over from the old server that was in the /home web app directory. Updated my post with the shell script.

Comment: It seems that the current Pylons version (1.0.2) is too new for your project. I think that 0.10 is the last version having `error_template` in `pylons.error` module, but I encountered more errors coming from other libraries Pylons depends on. Your best bet now is to carefully inspect `/home/webapp/pylons-env/lib/python*/site-packages` from the archive of the old server, write down all the libraries and their versions to `requirements.txt` (`Pylons==0.10` and so on, each in new line) and install using that.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I went and did as you said and now have the older version on the new machine. It did clear up most of the errors when I ran as `paster serve prod-mt.ini`. However, I tried to do the same thing on the old server and ran into the same errors. This leads me to believe that the .sh I posted above is essential to getting the app running. I have made sure the `paster` and `activate` files are identical between servers. Still when I run the script, the paster process never starts on the server. I've updated the above with the output when .sh is run.

Comment: To clarify, what I mean by "I tried to do the same thing on the old server" is I just ran the `paster serve prod-mt.ini` and got the same errors I was getting on the new server. However, the bash script runs fine on the old server and `paster` process starts fine, but does not on the new server.

Comment: One thing the shell script does that you might have missed is `cd /home/webapp/app`. Other than that, I don't know why running `paster` manually is not working even on the old server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that together with the webapp you extracted an old Python *virtual environment* (`/home/webapp/pylons-env`) which expects Python version from your old server. In order to fix this, you need to recreate virtual environment and install the packages that your webapp requires.

First you need `virtualenv` installed in your server (if you don't have it already).  I don't know CentOS very well, so the package name may differ:

```
sudo yum install python-virtualenv
```

Then remove old virtual environment and create new one:

```
rm -rf /home/webapp/pylons-env
virtualenv /home/webapp/pylons-env
```

I don't know how all the dependencies of your webapp were installed in the old virtualenv, but nowadays the common way of doing this is by using `pip` tool, which is included in the freshly created virtualenv. If you see `requirements.txt` file (the usual place to keep a list of all the dependencies) located next to your webapp, try running:

```
/home/webapp/pylons-env/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Otherwise you can enter the names of dependencies in the command line yourself (this will be `Pylons` at the very least, probably some others):

```
/home/webapp/pylons-env/bin/pip install Pylons
```

If your webapp has dependencies included in `setup.py` file, you can do this (note the dot at the end):

```
# Assuming, that setup.py is located at /home/webapp/app:
cd /home/webapp/app
/home/webapp/pylons-env/bin/pip install .
```

This would install the webapp and its dependencies into virtualenv.

These are quite common ways to install packages into virtualenv, you need to figure out yourself which one suits your project the best.

And do not worry that any of these methods will break something, because virtual environment is isolated from the system-wide Python installation by design and is also pretty cheap to recreate.

Comment: I followed your directions and have made some progress. I messed around with it for about 4 more hours and am apparently stuck again. I have updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks in large part to Audrius, got it all figured out. Had to recreate the virtualenv, run the setup.py for the app, and ended up having to go through and installing each dependency manually. In the bash script, it created a log file so I just ran the script and read the log file to see what errors were generated. As I resolved those one at a time--with the help of Google and Stack Overflow--it eventually got to a point where the paster would load the application. Running fine so far.